# How to broadcast video on live ip?

Tags: android, android-camera

[Ip Camera for Android](https://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/) is a nice camera application which we can easily view on local network. I have downloaded the code and it is working fine for Wifi local network. Now I want to make changes from local network to Internet so that this Ip Camera is available on anywhere in the world by live IP address and port.

To achieve this what change should I code ?  I am not asking for readymade code I am just asking for a way to broadcast it on live ip+port. Any logic and link will be helpful for me.